# Write one line code to get odd and even numbers in separate arrays

Tags: python, algorithm

I was asked this question in a tcs codevita interview. Given an array

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

you have to write a one line code in Python such that you get 2 different array/lists where one will contain odd numbers and the other will contain even numbers. i.e one list

```
odd = [1,3,5,7,9]
```

and other list

```
even =[2,4,6,8,10]
```

I was not able to write this code in one line. Can anyone tell me how to solve this in one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two list comprehensions in one line:

```
odd, even = [el for el in a if el % 2==1], [el for el in a if el % 2==0]

print(odd, even)
#([1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10])
```

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension holds the answer. 
But rather than comprehend on both even and odd list construction, pop one kind (even in this case) from you original list `a` and put in it's list and what you have left in `a` will be the other kind (odd):

```
>>> even, odd = [a.pop(index) for index, item in enumerate(a) if item % 2 == 0], a
>>> print(even,odd)
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10] [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Comment: This looks promising, but won't the indices go out of whack as soon as you pop something from the list you are traversing?

Comment: I would say that even if this approach is more elegant than mine, from an efficiency point of view it should be worse as it needs to change the list a and pop elements.

Comment: It's not messing up the indexes. Probably because of `enumerate(a)` which returned a counter over the iterable list which is an equivalent of the index I pop from `a`

Comment: @newbie But yours traverses the list twice, which isn't efficient either.

Comment: @tripleee yes sure, traversing once it's straightforward with a `for-loop`. I was just pointing out that there could be a huge difference in terms of time even if this solution is nicer. Consider a list `a = [random.randint(0, 1000) for r in range(100000)]`. I get `0.018s` vs `1.10s` of this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can slice the list with a step of 2:

```
odd, even = a[::2], a[1::2]
```

Comment: What will be the output of `[12,64,78,34,81]` so?

Comment: if it is given that a=  [12,34,345,56,32,46,7,67,342,3554,67,534] then how can we write the code in one line

Comment: @Divesh You should make `a = [12,34,345,56,32,46,7,67,342,3554,67,534]` the sample input of your question then.

Comment: @blhsing Seems you are selecting elements with odd indices instead of odd values

Comment: @MBo Yes I was basing my solution on the OP's given input and expected output.

Comment: @blhsing But he eventually used array with all odd elements at even places and vice versa. Not the best example :)

Answer (score 0):

Using key,to get in a single list

```
print(sorted(j,key=lambda x:(x%2,-a.index(x))))
```

Comment: Interesting, but a) does not literally `get 2 different array/lists` b) most likely does not run in O(n) time.

Answer (score 0):

```
Using list comprehension:    

def evenodd(myl): 
       evenlist = [num for num in myl if num % 2 == 0] 
       oddlist = [num for num in myl if num % 2 == 1]  
       print("Even numbers:", evenlist) 
       print("Odd numbers:", oddlist) 
      
    mylist=list()
    n=int(input("Enter the size of the  List:"))
    print("Enter the numbers:")
    for i in range(int(n)):
       k=int(input(""))
       mylist.append(k)
    evenodd(mylist)
```

Comment: codes only doesn't answer the question means that you have to give some explanation that will help an OP and other users in the future to know what was the problem or may you read [this documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)